# Is there any way to move expired data from one collection to another periodly?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have a very big collection, and for getting a better performance, we want to limit the size of "active" collection.

That means, we have two collection: "active" and "inactive", we need to keep the data of last 90 days in "active" collection, and move the data before 90 days to "inactive" collection automatically.

Is any way that we can do this automatically with mongodb?

Or is there any other solution we can achieve this target? (get better performance for querrying data in 90 days without deleting old data)

Comment: _"... get better performance for querying data in 90 days without deleting old data"_: Any query (find, update, delete or aggregation) on the collection can include a query filter specifying to select documents in the last 90 days. Create an index on the timestamp field (assuming there is a timestamp field on each document; if not create one with type `Date`). This way you can work with "active" data only _and_ the index will ensure the query is performant.

Comment: @prasad_, thank you prasad_, I will try it.